# How can I tell if I have tensorflow-gpu installed using python?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to differentiate within python whether a user has installed `tensorflow-gpu` or just `tensorflow` (on the CPU, which lacks GPU support).

I do not want to have to run a trivial model (with `log_device_placement`) to have to figure that out.

I have tried making use of `tensorflow.__version__`, but it seems like `1.3.0-rc2` is printed both ways.

Comment: None of the answers below is what you need?

Answer (score 4):

Was it installed via pip? You could check `pip list` and it will show either:

```
tensorflow-gpu
```

or

```
tensorflow
```

the second is the cpu version

Answer (score 2):

Run `pip freeze | grep tensorflow` if it's installed you will see `tensorflow-gpu` in the results.

If you want to check it programmatically within python, this is one way to go:

```
import pip 

l = next(str(i) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions() if 'tensorflow-gpu' in str(i))
print(l)
```

which outputs in my case:

```
tensorflow-gpu 0.12.0rc0
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Mohamed isn't working anymore in Python 3.6+ but below does work:

```
import pkg_resources
l = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set  if 'tensorflow' in str(d)]
print(l)
```